# Why does $(P \downarrow Q) \downarrow (P \downarrow Q) = (P \lor Q)$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

As a part of *How to Prove It: A Structured Approach* by Daniel J. Velleman, I have come across this problem:

> Find a formula only using the connective $\downarrow$ to write $P \lor Q$.

I was very stuck, so I decided to look up the answer. The answer involves using a truth table as follows:

| $P$ | $Q$ | $P \downarrow Q$ | $(P \downarrow Q) \downarrow (P \downarrow Q)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | F | T |
| T | F | F | T |
| F | T | F | T |
| F | F | T | F |

Yet, I cannot understand why. I do understand that this truth table is equivalent to the truth table of $(P \lor Q)$ and therefore it is equal. Yet, I do not understand why this truth tables comes out the way it does.

Would it be because both statements, the duplicate $(P \downarrow Q)$, are false, and therefore, as neither statements are true, $(P \downarrow Q) \downarrow (P \downarrow Q)$ is true?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you wrote is correct. If $P = Q = F$, then $P \downarrow Q = T$, in which case, we're evaluating $T \downarrow T = F$. In all three other cases, $P \downarrow Q = F$, in which case, we're evaluating $F \downarrow F = T$.

By the way, this connective is called **nor** and, by using De Morgan's laws, is equivalent to either of these two forms:
$$
P \downarrow Q = \lnot P \land \lnot Q = \lnot(P \lor Q). 
$$
Hence, we can resolve
\begin{align}
(P \downarrow Q) \downarrow (P \downarrow Q) 
&= \lnot (P \downarrow Q) \land \lnot (P \downarrow Q) \\
&= \lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q) \land \lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q) \\
&= (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor Q) \\
&= P \lor Q. 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much! I see how it is wise to simplify the two expressions to  $T$ or $F$ and work from there. The equations also helped me resolve my misunderstanding!